Discord Invite Link Tracker
Im trying to create a discord bot that when a user joins, it logs the name of the user that joined and gets the member's name of who sent the invite link. It recognises the user has joined and gives the users discord name, but gives "The invite code could not be determined for invisionuk2978" it doesnt give me the name of the user that invited the user

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildInvites,
    ],
});

const { TOKEN, ADMIN_ROLE_ID, SERVER_ID, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID } = require('./config.json');

// Create a Map to store invites for each guild
const guildInvites = new Map();

client.once('ready', async () => {
    console.log('Bot is online!');
    try {
        const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(SERVER_ID);
        if (!guild) {
            console.error(`Guild with ID ${SERVER_ID} not found.`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Bot is in the server: ${guild.name}`);
            const adminChannel = guild.channels.cache.get(ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID);
            if (!adminChannel) {
                console.error(`Admin channel with ID ${ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID} not found.`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Admin channel found: ${adminChannel.name}`);
            }

            // Fetch invites for the guild
            const fetchedInvites = await guild.invites.fetch();
            const codeUses = new Map();
            fetchedInvites.each(inv => codeUses.set(inv.code, inv.uses));

            guildInvites.set(guild.id, codeUses);
            console.log(`Invites for ${guild.name} have been fetched and stored.`);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching invites:', error);
    }
});

client.on('inviteCreate', async invite => {
    try {
        const invites = await invite.guild.invites.fetch();

        const codeUses = new Map();
        invites.each(inv => codeUses.set(inv.code, inv.uses));

        guildInvites.set(invite.guild.id, codeUses);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching invites:', error);
    }
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    try {
        const cachedInvites = guildInvites.get(member.guild.id);
        if (!cachedInvites) {
            console.log(`The invite code could not be determined for ${member.user.username}.`);
            return;
        }

        const newInvites = await member.guild.invites.fetch();
        
        let usedInvite;
        newInvites.each(inv => {
            const cachedInvite = cachedInvites.get(inv.code);
            if (cachedInvite && cachedInvite < inv.uses) {
                usedInvite = inv;
            }
        });

        if (usedInvite) {
            const inviter = usedInvite.inviter;
            console.log(`${member.user.tag} was invited by ${inviter.tag}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`The invite code could not be determined for ${member.user.username}.`);
        }

        newInvites.each(inv => cachedInvites.set(inv.code, inv.uses));
        guildInvites.set(member.guild.id, cachedInvites);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("OnGuildMemberAdd Error:", err);
    }
});

client.login(TOKEN);```



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
